# Subtract Two datetime (TimeStamp) and compare with interval in hours (int) in lambda query

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I need to achieve this.
(CurrentTimeStamp - CreateTimeStamp) > (interval in hours).
I tried with below code, not able to achieve and  get an exception.
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan Subtract(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0) + new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
return query.Where(m => now.Subtract(m.create_timestamp) >= m.interval);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the linq to entities can not transform the compare of TimeSpan to sql querys. Maybe you should use DbFunctions in System.Data.Entity to compare timespans or use the ef core.
It is the example of using DbFunctions

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now - new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0) + new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
return query.Where(m => DbFunctions.DiffSeconds(now,m.create_timestamp).Value >= m.interval.TotalSeconds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use DateTime.Compare? [DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.compare?view=netcore-3.1)

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
var removeMins = now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
//var addMins = now.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2));
var result = DateTime.Compare(now, removeMins);
if (result < 0)
{  
   Console.WriteLine($"Now({now}) is earlier than removeMin({removeMins})");
   //return query.Where(m => m.date == now);
}
else if (result == 0)
{
 Console.WriteLine($"Now({now}) is equal to removeMin({removeMins})");   
}
else
{
Console.WriteLine($"Now({now}) is later than  removeMin({removeMins})");
 //return query.Where(m => m.date == removeMins);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime todayDate = DateTime.Now;
TimeSpan difference = inputDate- todayDate;
Console.WriteLine(difference.Hours);
Console.WriteLine(difference.Days);
Console.WriteLine(difference.Minutes);
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you concatenate `IQueryable<...>` LINQ statements, property `Expression` of the IQueryable is changed. Only when you execute the IQueryable (using ToList, foreach, FirstOrDefault, Any, etc), the Expression is sent to the `IQueryable<...>.Provider` who will translate the Expression into SQL before executing the query.

The exception message says that your Provider does not know `DateTime.Subtract`. It depends a bit on the provider that you use (MicroSoft, SQLite, MySql, Mongo, ...), but most of them don't know `DateTime.Subtract.

Familiarize yourself with the list of [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities?redirectedfrom=MSDN), and the [DbFunctions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbfunctions?view=entity-framework-6.2.0). The latter contains several methods to do calculations with TimeSpans.

Apparently you want all items where CreateTimeStamp + Interval  <= now

```
query.Where(item => item.create_timestamp + item.interval <= now);
```

If your Provider doesn't support this, consider usiing `DbFunctions.AddSeconds` and `DbFunctions.DiffSeconds` (or milliseconds, or days, whatever resolution you need.